# there is no check box in Instance Features

Tags: sql-server

I try to install SQL Server 2008 R2, but there is no Checkbox Option in instance feature. I need help

This is the error:
[image: error]

Thank you

Comment: It appears as if you're installing **only** the Management Studio - not an actual **database engine** version .....

Comment: i think i already install databse engine http://i64.tinypic.com/f0da3s.png but when i install management studio again it's still error http://i65.tinypic.com/ohstw8.png

Answer (score 0):

This is most probably related to a previous installation of express components (e.g. tools only). If this is the case, then use Sql Server 2008 installation center(64-bit) -> Maintenance -> Edition upgrade rather than normal installation.

An alternative is to get a newer version of express ([SQL Server 2014 Express](https://www.microsoft.com/en-US/download/details.aspx?id=42299)) and benefit from newer features. If you really have to work in SQL Server 2008 compatibility for certain databases, you can [change the compatibility level](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/relational-databases/databases/view-or-change-the-compatibility-level-of-a-database) of those particular database.